# How to make both the website and dockerized webmail work together on same server

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, docker, email-server

I'm having new VPS machine where:

1. Install nginx on main host to serve my domain website (e.g. example.com) on ports 80,443. example.com conf in host nginx:

   ```
   server {
       server_name example.com www.example.com;
       root /var/www/www.example.com;
       listen 80;
       listen 443 ssl http2;
       listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
       ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/example.com_by_cloudflare.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example.com_by_cloudflare.key;
   }
   ```
2. Installed containerized mail server ([Poste.io2](https://poste.io/) docker) to serve emails @exmaple.com. Mailserver hostname: mail.example.com. It's also its own using nginx on ports 80, 443 to serve the webmail portal. ([Poste.io2](https://poste.io/) installed through this command:

   ```
   sudo docker run \
         --net=host \
         -e TZ=Etc/UTC \
         -v /var/posteiodata:/data \
         --name "posteiomailserver" \
         -h "mail.example.com" \
         -t analogic/poste.io
   ```

The problem is I want both the website (example.com) and the webmail (mail.example.com) to work. I'm not sure is this manageable through DNS, nginx/reverse proxy on host/docker? or not manageable in this way and I should change something.

Appreciate if you have advice.

P.S DNS managed by Cloudflare, DNS records looks like this:

```
mail.example.com.  1    IN  A           <server_ip_address>
example.com.       1    IN  A           <server_ip_address>
www.example.com.   1    IN  CNAME       example.com.
example.com.       1    IN  MX      0   mail.example.com.
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like a reverse proxy is the way to go. It listens on 80 and 443 for both subdomains and forwards the request to one of the servers. Both servers would expose other ports like 8080, 8443 for the webserver and 9090, 9443 for the mail server for example.

Comment: is it possible that main website (example.com) to be served on 80, 443 only. Webmail (mail.example.com) on any other port, eg 9090, 9443 as suggested. What would be nginx config?

Comment: You can change the host ports the docker container is bound to in the run command. docker run -p <host_port>:<container_port>. In your case something along the lines of docker run -p 9090:80. Check the documentation for all possibilities of assigning ports on https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue as follows:

1. Run docker with HTTP_PORT=5080 and HTTPS_PORT=4433 environment variables. This will make containerized nginx run on ports 5080, 4433:

```sh
sudo docker run \
       --net=host \
       -e TZ=UTC \
       -e "HTTP_PORT=5080" \
       -e "HTTPS_PORT=4433" \
       -v /var/posteiodata:/data \
       --name "posteiomailserver" 
       -h "mail.example.com" \
       -t analogic/poste.io
```

2. Open ports 4433, 5080 on host machine:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4433 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5080 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo service iptables save
```

3. Created nginx conf to forward 443 to 4433 when mail.example.com is opened:

`sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/mail.example.com`

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name mail.example.com;
  ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/example.com_by_cloudflare.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example.com_by_cloudflare.key;

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:4433;
  }
}
```

4. Enable the new config and start nginx:

```sh
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mail.example.com.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
sudo nginx -t
sudo service nginx start
```

Now I can browse my site on example.com and webmail on mail.example.com, voila!